# c# interface question

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have the following code:

```
// IMyInterface.cs

namespace InterfaceNamespace
{
    interface IMyInterface
    {
        void MethodToImplement();
    }
}
```

.

```
// InterfaceImplementer.cs
class InterfaceImplementer : IMyInterface
{
    void IMyInterface.MethodToImplement()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MethodToImplement() called.");
    }
}
```

**This code compiles just fine(why?)**. However when I try to use it:

```
// Main.cs

    static void Main()
    {
        InterfaceImplementer iImp = new InterfaceImplementer();
        iImp.MethodToImplement();
    }
```

I get:

> ```
> InterfaceImplementer does not contain a definition for 'MethodToImplement'
> ```

i.e. `MethodToImplement` is not visible from outside. But if I do the following changes:

```
// InterfaceImplementer.cs
class InterfaceImplementer : IMyInterface
{

    public void MethodToImplement()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MethodToImplement() called.");
    }
}
```

Then Main.cs also compiles fine. Why there is a difference between those two?

Comment: `This code compiles just fine`, no it doesn't. `'InterfaceNamespace' is a 'namepace' but is used like a 'type'`.

Comment: Certain parts of code is ommitted/renamed for simplicity & privacy. The sample code in question may not work when copy-pasted as it is, but it explains the problem nevertheless

Comment: **Then don't claim that it does!** (I fixed the error...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By [implementing an interface explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx), you're creating a private method that can only be called by casting to the interface.

Comment: +1 for the answer but I have a question....the implementer that does not work implements the the interface as "void InterfaceNamespace.MethodToImplement" can you help me make sense as to what that is actually doing? It is Namespace.InterfaceMethodName instead of Namespace.Interface.InterfaceMethodName...am I still sleeping?

Comment: @Craig: I was wondering about that too, it doesn't make sense and it won't compile, porbably an error in the question.

Comment: @H.B. right, of coucrse it wont compile...thanks thought maybe I was dreaming. You will get the is namespace but used like a type error. Probably just a typ like you said.

Comment: Hmmm.  Not sure you should be using the word "private" in that context.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is to support the situation where an interface method clashes with another method.  The idea of "Explicit Interface Implementations" was introduced.

Your first attempt is the explicit implementation, which requires working directly with an interface reference (not to a reference of something that implements the interface).

Your second attempt is the implicit implementation, which allows you to work with the implementing type as well.

To see explicit interface methods, you do the following:

```
MyType t = new MyType();
IMyInterface i = (IMyInterface)t.
i.CallExplicitMethod(); // Finds CallExplicitMethod
```

Should you then have the following:

```
IMyOtherInterface oi = (MyOtherInterface)t;
oi.CallExplicitMethod();
```

The type system can find the relevant methods on the correct type without clashing.

Answer (score 0):

if you are implementing an interface to a class then the methods in interface must be there in class and all methods should be public also.

```
class InterfaceImplementer : IMyInterface
{

    public void MethodToImplement()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MethodToImplement() called.");
    }
}
```

and you can call the method like this

```
IMyInterface _IMyInterface = new InterfaceImplementer();
IMyInterface.MethodToImplement();
```